# Access ES aggregation bucket list objects in laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to access Elasticquent aggregation bucket list objects in laravel:

```
array:1 [▼   "group_by_law_year" => array:3 [▼
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" => 0
    "sum_other_doc_count" => 0
    "buckets" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "key" => "2013"
        "doc_count" => 2
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "key" => "2012"
        "doc_count" => 1
      ]
    ]   ] ]
```

I tried like `$laws_y->getAggregations('group_by_law_year').get()`, but no success. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Normally, `$laws_y->getAggregations('group_by_law_year')` returns an `array`. What do you get when printing out that array using `print_r($aggs)`?

Comment: I get:

Array ( [group_by_law_year] => Array ( [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0 [sum_other_doc_count] => 0 [buckets] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 2013 [doc_count] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => 2012 [doc_count] => 1 ) ) ) )

How can I access buckets from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAggregations` will return an array (as shown in your output above), so you simply need to retrieve the `buckets` and iterate over them as shown below:

```
$buckets = $laws_y->getAggregations()['group_by_law_year']['buckets'];
foreach ($buckets as $bucket){
   echo $bucket['key'] . ' = ' . $bucket['doc_count'];
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that too, but when I try that I get: Undefined index: buckets